# L'uso della D eufonica

Tags: grammar

Pensavo di conoscere le regole fino ad oggi quando mi ha corretto Bing Chat. Si tratta delle seguenti parole: ad Amazon, secondo lui doveva essere "a Amazon" perché: 
"Amazon" inizia con la vocale "a", ma non è la stessa "a" che precede il nome. La preposizione "a" si scrive senza l'accento, mentre la prima lettera di "Amazon" si scrive con l'accento. Questo perché la preposizione "a" è una parola atona, cioè non ha una sillaba accentata, mentre "Amazon" è una parola tonica, cioè ha una sillaba accentata . Quindi, la preposizione "a" e la prima lettera di "Amazon" non sono la stessa vocale, ma due vocali diverse. Per questo motivo, si usa la preposizione "a" senza la "d" davanti a "Amazon". 
 Io però non sono riuscita a trovare nessuna specificazione al riguardo nel web e mi sembra naturale dire "ad Amazon" che "a Amazon". Spero di avere i vostri chiarimenti, grazie in anticipo.

Comment: Ma figuriamoci! Bing Chat e gli altri LLM si inventano letteralmente le cose, assemblando frammenti testuali nel loro corpus. Hai senz'altro ragione tu. Se ho tempo in un altro momento scrivo una risposta, o lo farà qualcun altro.

Comment: Hahaha grazie DaG, mi fido di te assolutamente. Essendo una straniera davanti a una spiegazione (quella dell'Ai) così articolata e logica non potevo non dargli un po' di credito. In questi tempi, anch'io sto utilizzando l'ai come strumento ausiliare per studiare l'italiano, finora il migliore secondo me è Chat GPT, è quello che dice meno balle. Grazie ancora.

Comment: They are Large Language Models, that is, tools designed to emit plausible language, not to provide factual information!

Comment: Mi trovo bene con ChatGPT, detto questo non bisogna credergli ciecamente, infatti verifico le sue risposte quasi sempre. Questa volta ho voluto provare con Bing Chat dello Skype e secondo me è decisamente inferiore in termini di qualità intellettive. Non gli ho chiesto di fornirmi informazioni, gli ho chiesto di correggermi un testo, se ci fossero errori. Non un ho insegnante quindi continuerò a farmi aiutare da ChatGPT.

Comment: Se posso permettermi, cerca un'alternativa (libri di esercizi, insegnanti, corsi on line etc.) perché con ChatGPT rischi di imparare cose sbagliate. Dici giustamente che non gli chiedi informazioni, ma gli errori trapelano comunque. Proprio di recente, in un altro contesto, ChatGPT mi ha detto che “sarebbe” è un congiuntivo...

Comment: La cosa buona è che ChatGPT chiede scusa senza problemi e senza vergognarsi. Non di rado gli correggo pure io qualcosa :D

Comment: @DaG - siamo passati da: è vero per lo dice la TV a e’ vero perché lo dice Internet e infine è vero perché lo dice l’intelligenza artificiale !!!

Comment: @wensi Complimenti per il tuo italiano!

Comment: @BakerStreet - un dubbio rimane; sta parlando wensi o chatGPT?

Comment: Eh lo so che ormai con questo ChatGpt spesso c'è il dubbio. Ma vabbe', in ogni caso l'italiano lo sa, anche comprendendo  bene quello che dice Chatgpt. Magari fossi io in grado di fare questo in cinese! Io però, leggendo gli altri suoi post, penso che lo sa veramente bene l'italiano.

Comment: @Hachi Sono io, io  ho ottenuto il C2 qualche anno fa.

Comment: @BakerStreet Grazie, ho ancora molto da imparare.

Answer (score 7):

L’uso delle vocali a ed e seguite da parole che cominciano con vocali si è evoluto nel tempo. Come spiega questo estratto le attuali tendenze sono le seguenti:

> C’è stato un lungo e tormentato dibattito sulla d eufonica, e fino a una cinquantina d’anni fa essa sembrò prevalere. Poi ha perso terreno. Ora, la conclusione generalmente condivisa è questa: ***eliminiamo la d eufonica quando la a o la e sono seguite da parola che cominci per una vocale diversa. Per esempio, diciamo e scriviamo a osservare, non ad osservare; e anche, non ed anche.***
>
> Eccezione, ormai imposta dall’uso, ad esempio, non a esempio. Quando
> invece a ed e sono seguite da parola iniziante per la stessa vocale,
> la d eufonica può, anzi deve essere mantenuta. Esempi: ed entrò, non e
> entrò; ad aspettare, non a aspettare.
>
> Queste sono le norme generalmente stabilite dalle redazioni dei giornali e delle case editrici. ***Resta il fatto che se a qualcuno la d eufonica piacesse a tal punto da usarla anche tra vocali diverse, come in ad osservare, ed anche, nessuno potrà impedirglielo accusandolo di violentare la lingua.*** Anzi, questa potrà tutt’al più essere considerata una ricercatezza.

([dizionari.corriere.it](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/A/a-ad.shtml?refresh_ce))

Comment: Grazie, ho letto con interesse la tua risposta.

Comment: Non la considererei una ricercatezza, ma uno stile personale, come evitare di scrivere "fra frati" e "tra travi". (Lo, non sono frasi che vengono normalmente usate.)